# How can I hide a div in JQuery mobile - current attempt hides div occasionally

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery JQuery and want to hide div on page load. To do this I am using the following javascript (in the page)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#some_div').hide();
    $('#some_btn').closest('.ui-btn').hide();
});
```

When the page is loaded sometimes the div and button are hidden, and sometimes they are not. There doesn't seem to be any consistancy I can see that determines when they are/aren't hidden. This occurs when I navigate to the page using the JQM ajaxy loads for standard links and when I refresh the page. I am using Chrome (latest). Any ideas on what may be going wrong here?

### Edit 1

As per request here's the html I'm using (which also includes @Omar suggestion of on pageshow)

```
<!doctype html>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"  > <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"  > <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"  > <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]> <html class="no-js" lang="en"  > <![endif]-->


    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">

        <link rel="stylesheet"  href="/static/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet"  href="/static/jquery-mobile/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">

        <script src="/static/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/jquery-mobile/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

      <!-- CSS: implied media="all" -->
    </head>

    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id = "main-page">
            <div data-role="header" style="overflow:hidden;">
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <div id = "some_div">
                    Test div
                </div>
                <button id = "some_btn">Test button</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function hide_things()
        {
            $('#some_div').hide();
            $('#some_btn').closest('.ui-btn').hide();
        }

        $(document).on('pageshow', '#main-page', function () 
        { 
            hide_things();
         });


        $( document ).ready(function() {
            hide_things();
        });

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why not having it hidden in css?

Comment: Can we see the html? Maybe a working example on jsFiddle?  @Sergio, I often hide things with JavaScript as a progressive enhancement - if JavaScript is disabled I still want the content to be visible.  If JavaScript is available, I use it to hide/show the content, for instance with an accordion.

Comment: Because you're using `.ready()` which shouldn't be used in JQM. Use JQM events `$(document).on('pageshow', '#pageid', function () { your code here });`

Comment: @ChrisRockwell, sure. That is why I asked. In some cases its good to have it visible.

Comment: Hi guys - thanks for chiming in. I've included a cut down version of the html. @Omar I've also tried to use the on pageshow method - but it's not working. I've tried it along with the document ready function and found that it doesn't work either. The div and button almost never hide on my mobile (iphone 4S - Chrome browser) but tends to hide on my Chrome Browser on my mac.

Comment: It should work, it depends where you place your code. In this demo I used class with display:none; as its recommended rather than using `.show()` which will add `display:block` when showing elements. http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/Q848L/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<div data-role="page" id = "main-page">
    <div data-role="header" style="overflow:hidden;"></div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id = "some_div">
            Test div
        </div>
        <button id = "some_btn">Test button</button>
    </div>
    $(document).on('pageinit', '#main-page', function () 
     {             
        var page = $('[data-role="page"]:last'); 
        page.find('#some_div').hide();
        page.find('#some_btn').closest('.ui-btn').hide();                 
     }); 
</div>
```

You could also try using pageshow, but for testing try unbinding the event first:
[Replace script above with:]

```
$(document).off('pageshow').on('pageshow', '#main-page', function () 
{
    var page = $('[data-role="page"]:last'); 
    page.find('#some_div').hide();
    page.find('#some_btn').closest('.ui-btn').hide();                 
 });
```

Cheers,

Comment: Hi @MartinOnTheNet - thanks for your time on this. The first way seems to work on initial page load but not after the ajax navigation to the page. Your second way worked perfectly though for all use cases :)

Comment: `var page = $.mobile.activePage;` is easier :)

Comment: Hi omar, i agree on that, but it also depends when you use it. For example if you have a popup or dialog they are also treated as active pages. So from experience the way I mentioned is safer in all aspects. Of course for this case both will be valid :)

Answer (score 0):

You should indeed be using the pageshow event in JQM, I have this working here: http://www.nextdesigns.ca/jqm/index.html

The code is as follows:

```
<body> 
    <div data-role="page" id = "main-page">
            <div data-role="header" style="overflow:hidden;">
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <div id = "some_div">
                    Test div
                </div>
                <button id = "some_btn">Test button</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function hide_things()
        {
            $('#some_div').hide();
            $('#some_btn').closest('.ui-btn').hide();
        }

        $(document).on('pageshow', '#main-page', function () 
        { 
            alert("About to hide your stuff!");
            hide_things();
         });
    </script>
</body>
```